# jQuery: Toggle disabled state based on sibling checkboxes, en masse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Each field in the HTML has a checkbox next to a text input, like so:

```html
<div class="field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox1" />
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
    <input type="text" id="textbox2" />
</div>
```

Using [jQuery's Attribute Starts With Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), it's easy to tie the click event on each checkbox with the disabled state of its sibling textbox -- this already works well:

```js
$("input[id^='checkbox']").click(function() {
    $(this).siblings().prop("disabled", !this.checked);
});
```

What I can't figure out is a similar concise statement I can run one time (from another event) that will toggle all of these textboxes based on the current checked state of their associated checkboxes. Here's roughly what I assumed it should be, but it merely toggles all of them instead of each individually as appropriate -- i.e. it does not work:

```js
$("input[id^='textbox']").prop("disabled", $(this).prev().is(':checked'));
```

I've also tried this with a change handler, but it isn't triggering when the checkboxes themselves are re-enabled.

Any suggestions for me?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If I have understood you properly, you want to *enable* text input if corresponding checkbox **is** checked. Suggested approach:

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
  $(this).next().prop('disabled', !this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
  <input type="text" disabled id="textbox1" />
</div>
<div class="field">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
  <input type="text" disabled id="textbox2" />
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, good point -- the change handler is a nice way of keeping these sync'ed. What I didn't explain in my question (because I was trying to simplify it) is that I'm looking to kick off the enabling/disabling after other changes -- specifically, an entire section of the form could be disabled and re-enabled. The change handler doesn't catch the enable/disable changes :(

Comment: @ewall You want to disable/enable all text inputs at once?

Comment: I have other events that disable or enable the entire section of the form. When this section is enabled, I need it to trigger the enabling/disabling of the text fields according to their checkboxes. The change handler doesn't trigger when the checkboxes are enabled.

Comment: @ewall You want to dismount the `change` listener when *some other event* is enabled?

Comment: I guess I'd like to trigger the handler when the checkboxes become enabled.

Comment: @ewall So you want to trigger *some function* when all checkboxes from the form are enabled?

Comment: More like this: when the checkbox becomes enabled, I want it to enable or disable the textbox based on whether the checkbox is checked or not. Now I'm thinking I may need to use propHooks to watch the "disabled" property thus trigger the check...

Comment: @ewall I would like to help you, but I just can't get your point... :(

Comment: I figured out a way using jQuery.propHooks, but it's so different than my question. Think I'll just try to give you some points then vote my own question out of existence!

Answer (score 0):

Other than `change` event, you can use `click` event besides the related `sibling` query to access the textbox next to the checkbox. And the update in your comment, you can use a `fieldset` element to achieve what you want:

```js
$(".field > :checkbox").on("click", function(){
if($(this).is(":checked")){
   $(this).siblings("fieldset").removeAttr("disabled");
}else{
   $(this).siblings("fieldset").attr("disabled","disabled");
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" />
    <fieldset disabled="disabled" >
      <input type="text" id="textbox1-1" />
      <input type="text" id="textbox1-2" />
      <textarea id="textarea-1"></textarea>
      <input type="checkbox">Test 1
    </fieldset>  
</div>
<div class="field">
    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" />
    <fieldset disabled="disabled" >
      <input type="text" id="textbox2-1" />
      <input type="text" id="textbox2-2" />
      <textarea id="textarea-2"></textarea>
      <input type="checkbox">Test 2
    </fieldset>    
</div>
```

Comment: True. Sadly, I'm not explaining very well why I'm looking for a one-time command I can run to enable/disable all the fields based on the status of their checkboxes. Each individual click or change event I can do.